# Looking for a family of functions

Tags: inequality, functional-equations

Let $f$, defined on $\mathbb{R_+}$, be concave and increasing, and $g$, also defined on $\mathbb{R_+}$ be convex and increasing, with $f(0) = g(0) = 0$.

What kind of minimal conditions do we need on $f$ and $g$ to guarantee that
$Argmax (f(x)-g(x)) \leq Argmax (f(\alpha x) - g(x))$ for any $\alpha \geq 1$.

Any help welcome.

Comment: Your "related question" should not be in this post, but either in another one or nowhere. And your first question lacks some presentation of what you tried.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be positive? Note that your inequation is equivalent to $yf(y)\ge xf(x)$ for any $y\ge x.$

Comment: Sorry, I will restate only the second question then. And for the first one I made a mistake, f is decreasing. But yes it's positive.